# React Accessible SVG Chart: aria-activedescendant not working

Tags: svg, charts, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to implement a very simple chart to test and improve my accessibility skills. The chart consists of a fruit distribution and I want each element inside the chart to be read by screen readers and navigable by the keyboard. I added a tabIndex="0" to my svg root element and put a title with a high level explanation of the chart. Then, I added keydown listeners for both up and down keys and move inside the chart data (changing the active element properly). Visually everything works ok, and I can see that the aria-activedescendant is changed to the correct element. I was hoping the screen reader (in my case voice over) would understand that the active descendant changed and read the label for each chart data, but this is not happening.

**This is the chart code:**

```
var Graph = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      activeBarIndex: 0
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var chartNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);  
    chartNode.addEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyDown);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    var chartNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);  
    chartNode.removeEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyDown);
  },

  _onPreviousBar: function () {
    var totalBars = (
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.barGroup).childNodes.length
    );

    var barIndex = this.state.activeBarIndex - 1;
    if (barIndex < 0) {
      barIndex = totalBars - 1;
    }

    this.setState({activeBarIndex: barIndex});
  },

  _onNextBar: function () {
    var totalBars = (
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.barGroup).childNodes.length
    );

    var barIndex = this.state.activeBarIndex + 1;
    if (barIndex >= totalBars) {
      barIndex = 0;
    }

    this.setState({activeBarIndex: barIndex});  
  },

  _onKeyDown: function (e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    switch (key) {
      case 38:
        this._onPreviousBar();
        break;
      case 40:
        this._onNextBar();
        break;
    }
  },

  render: function () {

    var data = [
      {
        fruit: 'apples',
        count: 4
      },
      {
        fruit: 'oranges',
        count: 8
      },
      {
        fruit: 'pinnaples',
        count: 12
      }
    ];

    var activeDescendant = 'apples_bar';
    var barGroups = data.map(function (bar, index) {
      var barClass = 'bar';
      if (this.state.activeBarIndex === index) {
        barClass += ' bar--active';
        activeDescendant = bar.fruit + '_bar';
      }

      return (
        <g id={bar.fruit + '_bar'} role="img" className={barClass} aria-labelledby={bar.fruit + '_text'}>
          <rect role="presentation" width={bar.count * 10} height="19" y={20 * index}></rect>
          <text id={bar.fruit + '_text'} x={(bar.count * 10) + 5} y={(20 * index) + 10} dy=".30em">{bar.count + ' ' + bar.fruit}</text>
        </g>
      );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <svg version="1.1" className="chart" ref="chart" width="420" height="150"
        aria-labelledby="chart_title" role="img" aria-activedescendant={activeDescendant} tabIndex="0">
        <title id="chart_title">Bar chart with fruit distribution</title>
        <g ref="barGroup">
          {barGroups}
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }
});

var element = document.getElementById('content');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Graph), element);
```

You can view it live [here](http://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/VewapK?editors=001)

**Question**: What is missing for the screen reader to understand I'm changing the active element?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by adding `grid` role in the SVG root tag. and `gridcell` in each internal group.

This is the updated code that works fine. Also I've updated my codepen script.

Please post an answer if you believe there is a better solution to this problem!

```
var Graph = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      activeBarIndex: 0
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var chartNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);  
    chartNode.addEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyDown);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function () {
    var chartNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);  
    chartNode.removeEventListener("keydown", this._onKeyDown);
  },

  _onPreviousBar: function () {
    var totalBars = (
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.barGroup).childNodes.length
    );

    var barIndex = this.state.activeBarIndex - 1;
    if (barIndex < 0) {
      barIndex = totalBars - 1;
    }

    this.setState({activeBarIndex: barIndex});
  },

  _onNextBar: function () {
    var totalBars = (
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.barGroup).childNodes.length
    );

    var barIndex = this.state.activeBarIndex + 1;
    if (barIndex >= totalBars) {
      barIndex = 0;
    }

    this.setState({activeBarIndex: barIndex});  
  },

  _onKeyDown: function (e) {
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

    switch (key) {
      case 38:
        this._onPreviousBar();
        break;
      case 40:
        this._onNextBar();
        break;
    }
  },

  render: function () {

    var data = [
      {
        fruit: 'apples',
        count: 4
      },
      {
        fruit: 'oranges',
        count: 8
      },
      {
        fruit: 'pinnaples',
        count: 12
      }
    ];

    var activeDescendant = 'apples_bar';
    var barGroups = data.map(function (bar, index) {
      var barClass = 'bar';
      if (this.state.activeBarIndex === index) {
        barClass += ' bar--active';
        activeDescendant = bar.fruit + '_bar';
      }

      return (
        <g id={bar.fruit + '_bar'} role="gridcell" className={barClass}>
          <rect role="presentation" width={bar.count * 10} height="19" y={20 * index}></rect>
          <text x={(bar.count * 10) + 5} y={(20 * index) + 10} dy=".30em">{bar.count + ' ' + bar.fruit}</text>
        </g>
      );
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <svg version="1.1" className="chart" ref="chart" width="420" height="150" aria-readonly="true"
        aria-labelledby="chart_title" role="grid" aria-activedescendant={activeDescendant} tabIndex="0">
        <title id="chart_title">Bar chart with fruit distribution</title>
        <g ref="barGroup" role="row">
          {barGroups}
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }
});

var element = document.getElementById('content');
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Graph), element);
```

Comment: aria-activedescendant only works for certain roles at the moment. This is probably the best solution but you will want to test to make sure it works in other AT. e.g. NVDA/JAWS on Windows.

Another issues you may want to address is the keyboard commands will not work on iOS with a bluetooth keyboard, so you may want to add support for other shortcuts.

Another issue you will want to look into is to ensure that the grid markup is complete. Gridcell needs a row parent.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I will make sure Jaws ans Nvda will be tested as well. Regarding the row parent it is there in the parent group.